# Delayed OnParametersSetAsync task triggers duplicate OnParametersSet of child components

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to avoid repetitive OnParametersSet events from triggering in child components when the parent page/component has a "long" running OnParametersSet event of its own. For example, here's a basic page with some child components.

```
@page "/test"

<Node>
    <Node>
        <Node></Node>
    </Node>
</Node>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Page: OnInitializedAsync - start");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Page: OnInitializedAsync - finish");
    }
}
```

The node component is very simple as well:

```
<div>Node: @GetHashCode()</div>
@ChildContent

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Node {0}: OnParametersSet", GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Here is what I see in the console. Note that after the page has finished its OnParametersSet event, two of the three child components call OnParametersSet again.

```
Page: OnInitializedAsync - start
Node 924945978: OnParametersSet
Node 1026183343: OnParametersSet
Node 213373360: OnParametersSet
Page: OnInitializedAsync - finish
Node 924945978: OnParametersSet
Node 1026183343: OnParametersSet
```

Is this just a flaw with Blazor or is there a better way to avoid these extra events? The node components have nothing to do with the content on the page itself. In the real world I may have many child components, each that are trying to fetch data async so I want to prevent these extra events from firing.

The only workaround I've found is to wrap the nodes block with an @if(pageSetParametersEventHasFinished) statement that prevents the node components from initializing until the page is "ready".

Comment: Noted and corrected.

Comment: There's a box you should check when you want to answer your own question. See: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.)  Good question though. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with an abstract component like the following that handles parameter changes.

```
public abstract class WatchComponent : ComponentBase
{
    private bool _isDirty = true;
    private bool _shouldRender = true;

    protected abstract Task OnParametersChangedAsync();

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (!_isDirty) return;

        await OnParametersChangedAsync();
        _isDirty = false;
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        _shouldRender = false; // disable if child component has RenderFragment parameter
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: OnAfterRender", GetHashCode());
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRender() => _shouldRender;

    protected void SetField<T>(ref T field, T value)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return;
        Console.WriteLine("parameter changed from {0} to {1}", field, value);
        field = value;
        _isDirty = true;
        _shouldRender = true;
    }
}
```

Using this with the demo from above I tried the following and everything seemed to work.

Updated page:

```
@page "/test"

<Node Value="@_value1">
    <Node Value="@_value2">
        <Node></Node>
    </Node>
</Node>

@code {
    private string _value1 = "v1";
    private string _value2 = "v2";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Page: OnInitializedAsync - start");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Page: OnInitializedAsync - finish");
        _value1 = "v1.1";
        _value2 = "v2";
    }
}
```

Updated Node component:

```
@inherits WatchComponent

<div>Node: @GetHashCode(), Value="@Value"</div>

@ChildContent

@code {

    private string _value;
    [Parameter]
    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => SetField(ref _value, value);
    }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override Task OnParametersChangedAsync()
    {
        // load something async here
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The console output:

```
Page: OnInitializedAsync - start
parameter changed from  to v1
parameter changed from  to v2
833522111: OnAfterRender
854912238: OnAfterRender
668729564: OnAfterRender
Page: OnInitializedAsync - finish
parameter changed from v1 to v1.1
833522111: OnAfterRender
```

Answer (score 5):

This is by design. Note that the 2 outer Nodes are rendered twice because they have ChildContent. The inner Node is already 'stable'.

Blazor 'errs on the safe side', it can't guarantee nothing changed in the ChildContent.

But OnParametersSet is (should be) a light operation, not a problem in itself. Worry about the Render action that follows it.

My best practice for parameters

- keep a copy inside the component
- only when the new value differs from the copy, do fetch-data or other work
- for a heavy component, use ShouldRender() to minimize re-rendering.
  That looks like this

```
bool shouldRender = true;

protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
   ...
   shouldRender = false;
}

protected override bool ShouldRender()
{
    return shouldRender;
}

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{        
    if (myCopy != Param)
    {
      myCopy = Param;      
      shouldRender = true;
      ...  // fetch or process data
    }
}
```

This is only worth the effort for components that are 'heavy' in rendering and/or in processing data.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. Keeping an extra copy of every parameter in the entire project just seems excessive and very labor intensive but maybe that's all we can do at this point.

Comment: Not every parameter - read about simple vs complex types for params. I usually do this when it's an ItemId that's used  to fetch data.

Comment: I swapped most my route parameters to strings to avoid some OnSetParameters calls but even so there are situations like the above where it doesn't matter what the parameter type is, OnSetParameters will be called regardless because of how components are nested within each other.

Comment: And do your components 'know' when they need to be re-renderd or not? If so, override ShouldRender.  Keeping copies of the values can help with that.

Comment: I haven't been tracking that as closely as the OnSetParameters event. If I notice that no parameters have changed during a OnSetParameters event is it best practice to return false for ShouldRender thereafter until something actually changes?

Comment: Thanks for the example. I appended the original question with something that can handle parameter changes at an abstract level, similar to your approach. I think that will simply things a great deal.

Comment: It's good to see the community is coming up with solution to Blazor mess. But why should we accept this and write so much more code?

Answer (score 0):

### Revised Answer

Firstly, you can stop rendering sub-components until the data is loaded with a simple checker.

```
@page "/"

@if (loaded)
{
    <Node>
        <Node>
            <Node></Node>
        </Node>
    </Node>
}

@code {
    private bool loaded;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Page: OnInitializedAsync - start");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        loaded = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Page: OnInitializedAsync - finish");
    }
}
```

During a component render event, the `Renderer` calls `SetParametersAsync` on any sub-component where one of the parameters has changed, or one of the parameters is an object.  There's no standard equality checker for objects.

`ChildContent` and any other `RenderFragment` is a special case.  These are delegates - references to code blocks in the parent that are executed in the context of the parent. If the parent needs to render then so does any component referencing `RenderFragment` delegates. So the Renderer always re-renders sub-components containing valid `RenderFragments`.

In your code:

```
    <Node>
        <Node>
            <Node></Node>
        </Node>
    </Node>
```

```
        <Node>
            <Node></Node>
        </Node>
```

is a `RenderFragment` which is why the outer and middle `Nodes` gets re-rendered.

If you have no `RenderFragements` then you can use a `Record` to pass data into the component and do a manual equality check.

The following code demonstrates this:

A record to hold the data

```
public record MyComponentData
{
    public string? Message { get; set; }
}
```

A simple component with inline comments

```
<div class="m-s p-2">
    Data : @this.ComponentData.Message
</div>

<div class="m-s p-2">
    On Params Called : @this.OnParamsCalled
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public MyComponentData ComponentData { get; set; } = new();

    private MyComponentData CurrentComponentData { get; set; } = new();

    private int OnParamsCalled = 0;

    private bool isInit = true;

    // SetParametersAsync is the method the Renderer calls on the Component to init an update
    public async override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        //  ALWAYS do this first - it releases the ParameterView back to the Renderer
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        
        // As we are using records we can do a equality check
        var isupdate = this.CurrentComponentData != this.ComponentData;
        
        if (isInit | isupdate)
        {
            // If this is the first time or we have a record change runs the full ComponentBase process
            // by calling the base SetParametersAsync.  
            // Note we pass it ParameterView.Empty as we have already set the parameters in the first line
            await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);

            // Set the record to the new record
            this.CurrentComponentData = ComponentData;
        }

        // set IsInit to false
        isInit = false;
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        OnParamsCalled++;
        Debug.WriteLine("Component: OnParametersSet - called ");
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

And a test page:

```
@page "/"

<MyComponent ComponentData=this.myComponentData />

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick=UpdateData>Update Message</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick=UpdateNothing>Update Message</button>
</div>

@code {
    private MyComponentData myComponentData = new MyComponentData();

    private void UpdateData()
    {
        myComponentData = myComponentData with { Message = $"Updated at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}" };
    }

    private async Task UpdateNothing()
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Page: OnInitializedAsync - start");
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Debug.WriteLine("Page: OnInitializedAsync - finish");
    }
}
```

### Original Answer

> Is this just a flaw with Blazor

Why Flaw?  Are you suggesting that Blazor's basic design is flawed?

Any `OnInitializedAsync` that yields has two Render events.

1. When a method in `OnInitializedAsync` yields.
2. When `OnParametersSetAsync` completes.

This is by design.  Normally this is used to present a "Loading" message in the component until the data associated with the method is loaded.

The render process simply updates the Renderer's version of the DOM.  Only changes to the DOM get transmitted to the browser DOM.

Comment: Flawed in the sense that OnSetParameters is called extremely excessively by the framework even when no changes have actually occurred.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make some suggestions based on the updated information in your question.