# Can you subscribe / observe an object has changed in a Blazor component

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

Blazor seems aware of object changes within components without any external user intervention, for example if I have:

```
<p>@Data.SomeProperty</p>
<input type="text" @bind="Data.SomeProperty" />

@code {
   [Parameter]SomeModel Data {get;set;} // How do I know when this/its internals have changed?
}
```

Whenever the input changes it seems to understand that it needs to refresh the UI (not sure if its whole UI or just the specific parts changed). So is there a way for a developer to hook into this and be notified when something has changed?

My use case here is I want to be able to have a `title` field for a component (ComponentA) but the title is computed within a child component (ComponentB) so I want to be able to have ComponentB raise an event or notify in some way to indicate the computed property has changed then ComponentA can take that change and update its title.

So is there a way to be able to notify externally that the models changed WITHOUT altering the models internals? (Happy for it to be a custom `EventCallback` I somehow trigger as long as logic for it lives inside the component not the model)

Comment: I see nothing but EventCallback you rise when "computation" is done in ComponentB. Capture that callback and change some value in ComponentA and it will render it right away... I have to say I don't understand what you mean by "altering the models internals".. Maybe more code would help.

Comment: @Alamakanambra so I can put an `EventCallback<string>` in ComponentB which represents the "title has changed" event, but how do I KNOW in ComponentB that data has changed? Ultimately I want a way to be able to know inside a component if the params/properties have changed and raise an event off the back of that. Ideally in the scope of a property i.e no point raising "title changed" if some other variable changed

Comment: You have to fire the EventCallback manually.... Well, you can fire it from the inside of a property setter... I guess you know that already. Sample would be a good way to explain all the issues. Or are you leaning towards something like NotifyPropertyChanged from Windows Desktop ?

Comment: @Alamakanambra as mentioned I cant/dont want to have to change the model in any way, I could proxy the get set for the parameter but that wouldnt indicate that `Data.SomeChildProperty` has changed, which is mainly what I would be wanting to listen for, current Henks answer probably seems to be closest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have `[Parameter]SomeModel Data {get;set;}` which is oneway communication from parent (ComponentA) to the child (ComponentB).

For the reverse direction you can use an `[Parameter]EventCallback<string> OnChange { get set;}`. Or use a StateManager object as a cascading value.

Your main questions seems to be

> but how do I KNOW in ComponentB that data has changed?

That is easy, just use

```
override onParametersSet()
{
   // ... compute title 
   OnChange.InvokeAsync(title);
}
```

But you could easily get into a loop here, depending on how you handle this in the Parent.

Comment: Ah ok I didnt know this existed, it doesnt tell me whats changed, so I do worry that I may be firing changed events when it hasnt actually changed, but I could always potentially have some `lastValue` style thing to actually compare to see if its changed.

Comment: Yes, have a look at [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71709022/60761)

Comment: Hmm I am having some limited success with this, so if I go and change the value in an input box i.e `<input @bind-Value="Data.SomeTextValue"/>` its not firing `OnParametersSet()` for some reason not if I alter a select box which is bound to the underlying data object, however if I do something on the parent it does seem to trigger the `OnParameterSet` method.

Comment: I tried to explain that in the linked Answer: When CompA renders it will always render CompB to (and set the parameters) because SomeModel  is 'complex'. When you have a string or bool Parameter then Blazor does 'smart updates', but here you will have to implement that logic.